# Permalink Issues by Installing WordPress in Subdirectory - Post Name issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I install WordPress in my subdirectory.
All things are good, but when I change the permalinks into the post name, the problems start.

My, all post links redirect to my main site.

I Follow many kinds of instructions from the web, stack flow, and StackExchange.

I follow up on this questions answer, but I can find my solution
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67332/permalink-issues-by-installing-wordpress-in-subdirectory-subfolder

Can anyone tell me what exactly I have to do? I changed my site name from the general section, cut or copy the .htaccess and index.php file. That method did not work when I copy or cut the .htaccess and index.php file from a subdirectory and paste it on the root that automatically replaced or copy a file like .htacces(1), index(1).php
I also tried to delete the .htaccess and index.php file from the subdirectory that also not worked.
I changed the .htaccess file and index.php code, which is recommended https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67332/permalink-issues-by-installing-wordpress-in-subdirectory-subfolder this question but still not getting the solution.

Can any please tell me the full process of that?

Answer (score 0):

Add or update the following two-line in your wp-config.php

WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME must be the same.

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.yourdomainname.com/your_sub_direcory');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.yourdomainname.com/your_sub_direcory');`

Comment: Which one to edit? My root domain wp-config? or my subdirectory wp-config file?

Comment: In Your Subdirectory.

Comment: Ok then open your database in Phpmyadmin and check both links are proper or not in the wp_options table.

Comment: Make sure your _options table (WP_SITEURL) and (WP_HOME) URL are the same.
I am waiting for your reply...

Comment: Now go to your WP admin and then  Settings--->Permalink ---> Click on the Save Changes button.

If it's not working then please share your website link with me.

Comment: Not working. I tried before and now. Can I mail you or any discord account to talk to you?

Comment: Please verify that the no redirection code in your .htaccess file.

Comment: yes no redirection code on my .htacceess file

Comment: Make sure there is no server-side cache for your website.

Comment: There is one by default server cache installed called stack cache. I had been tried to purge it.

Comment: Yes ok do it and check

Comment: its working or not, Can you please share your problem with screenshot. here

Comment: not working.. sorry for the late reply i can't sent you a screenshot here, 

Comment: Do you have a discord account? send me e a Hello at @jefranulislam#9123

Comment: no i have no any discord account. Ok then try yourself